# How to split a string into an array, but rather chain new elements instead of adding an element per delimiter in php?

Tags: php, arrays, split

I know how to do that with a loop obviously, but I wonder if there was a one line for turning this:

```
a/b/c/d
```

into

```
[a, a/b, a/b/c, a/b/c/d]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a one-liner exactly, but you can do this with [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$arr = array_reduce(explode('/', 'a/b/c/d'), function($accumulator, $char) {
    $prev = empty($accumulator) ? '' : $accumulator[count($accumulator)-1] . '/';
    $accumulator[] = $prev.$char;
    return $accumulator;
}, []);
```

Comment: this returns `aababcabcd` which is correct for the original question, but I need to include the `/`s, so `$accumulator[] = $prev . $char . '/';` seems right but it also adds an `/` to the end. any idea?

Comment: In that case you want to define `$prev` as having a trailing slash, if it's not empty. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

has a semi-colon in the closure, so I guess it's technically a two-liner

```
echo json_encode(array_map(function($val,&$accumulator){return $accumulator=$accumulator.$val; },explode('/','a/b/c/d'),array()));
```

Results in this:

```
["a","ab","abc","abcd"]
```